# Creating a kaleidoscope effect from an image using opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to create a kaleidoscope from an image using opencv and am trying to grasp the mathematics involved. I understand that I have to segment the image into pieces, reflect it and rotate it 60 degrees creating a polygon of 6 triangles. What I am not understanding is how to break the image up and which pieces of the image to use and which to discard. Any ideas or links would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: unless you need extremely high resolution or extremely high precision, it's probably easier to use OpenGL rather than OpenCV

Comment: I agree but it's for a computer vision class thus I must use opencv.

Comment: Well, I haven't played much with OpenCV so I can't be much help there but it seems to me to be an impractical assignment/example.  Computer vision is about getting computers to understand the physical world in some manner.  Intentionally distorting an image serves only to make that goal more difficult to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

[here](https://github.com/SaranshKejriwal/Kaleidoscope) you will find a sample implementation using OpenCV

```
#include<opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include<opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include<opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include<iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Mat img,img2,kal1(400,400,CV_8UC3,Scalar(0,0,0));
    Mat kal2,add;
    VideoCapture cap(0);
    int i=0,j=0;
    for(;;)
    {
        cap>>img;
        resize(img,img,Size(400,400));
        for(i=0;i<600;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<i/3;j++)
            {
                    kal1.at<uchar>(Point(i,j))=img.at<uchar>(Point(i,j));//gives 1/8 of img

                if(j>i)
                {
                    continue;
                }
            }

        }
        flip(kal1,kal2,0);
        addWeighted(kal1,1,kal2,1,0,add);
        flip(kal2,kal2,1);
        addWeighted(add,1,kal2,1,0,add);
        flip(kal2,kal2,0);
        addWeighted(add,1,kal2,1,0,add);
        transpose(kal2,kal2);
        addWeighted(add,1,kal2,1,0,add);
        flip(kal2,kal2,0);
        addWeighted(add,1,kal2,1,0,add);
        flip(kal2,kal2,1);
        addWeighted(add,1,kal2,1,0,add);
        flip(kal2,kal2,0);
        addWeighted(add,1,kal2,1,0,add);
        line(img,Point(200,0),Point(200,200),Scalar(0,255,255),1);
        line(img,Point(0,0),Point(200,200),Scalar(0,255,255),1);
        moveWindow("img",30,30);
        moveWindow("Kaleidoscope",500,30);
        imshow("img",img);
        imshow("Kaleidoscope",add);
        waitKey(10);
    }

    return 1;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The math part seems to be the important part of your assignment, so I'll leave that up to you. However, if you think of the problem backwards, it might be slightly easier. Start with the kaleidoscope fractal pattern and determine how each segment in that pattern is created by the original image.

Once you have the pattern, all you have to do is make a map that maps each pixel in the pattern to a pixel in the image and use an OpenCV function such as [remap](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html?highlight=remap#remap) to do the actual mapping.

Comment: Okay what I have to do is cut an equilateral triangle then rotate it around a pivot point creating a hexagon. I can create 2 loops, one for the number of rows of polygons I want, one for the number of columns of polygons. What I'm trying to figure out is how to cut this triangle. I know I should create a black image and fill in the pixels where the triangle should be but how I do this I am confused about. Any ideas?